# How to wait until system under test's internal Observer has executed its lambda

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mockk

I'm testing `MyFragment` using MockK. The fragment registers an `Observer` for a public, mutable `LiveData` in the `onViewCreated` method. The `Observer` calls a method within a mocked ViewModel. However (based on reading log output, in the unit test, `verify` appears to run before the `Observer` can begin its lambda.

My unit test:

```
class Tests {
    @get:Rule val rule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
    //...
    @Test
    fun updates_vm_with_editingListener() {
        /* Given */
        val listener = MutableLiveData(false)
        fragment.editingListener = listener
        mActivity.setFragment(fragment) // <-- this attaches the fragment to a dummy activity

        /* When */
        listener.value = true

        /* Then */
        Log.d("MyFragmentTest", "running verify")
        verify { vm.instruct(ReadWriteObj) } // vm is a mockk'ed class
    }
}
```

MyFragment contains this code:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        editingListener.observe(this, Observer {
            Log.d(TAG, "editing changed to $it")
            when(it) {
                true -> mViewModel.instruct(ReadWriteObj)
                false -> mViewModel.instruct(ReadOnlyObj)
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "editing messaged mViewModel")
        })
    }
```

The relevant log output is:

```
I/TestRunner: started: updates_vm_with_editingListener(FragmentTest)
D/FragmentTest: running verify
D/MyFragment: editing changed to true
D/MyFragment: editing messaged mViewModel
E/TestRunner: failed: updates_vm_with_editingListener(FragmentTest)
E/TestRunner: java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: MyViewModel(vm#1).instruct(eq(ReadWriteObj@2da49cd))). Only one matching call to LiftGroupCardViewModel(vm#1)/instruct(LiftGroupCardIntent) happened, but arguments are not matching:
```

And the matched obj with different arguments is a call made in the fragment's `init` block and isn't under test here.

I don't understand. The `InstantTaskExecutorRule` in my class should make the `LiveData` observer trigger immediately when the value is changed rather than in the next cycle/loop thing.

**Edit**

Shouldn't what actually happens be:

1. mock viewmodel created and injected into fragment
2. dummy livedata (`listener`) injected into fragment
3. test begins
4. fragment attached to activity
5. fragment begins observing `listener`
6. `listener` value changes
7. fragment's observer fires, calling `viewmodel.instruct(ReadWriteObj)`
8. `verify` confirms `viewmodel.instruct` was called with `ReadWriteObj`

**Edit 2**

I know I could insert `Thread.sleep(1000)` in my unit test to fix this, but that is a really funky code smell. Right now, there is about 500ms between the verify and the observer behavior, and that's on a laptop from 2013. If this unit test were run, in theory, on some slower machine, the sleep might not fix the problem at all.